# Как в винде обрезать файл до нужного размера?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Именно обрезать, а не скопировать частично. Соответственно, у винды нет богатых инструментов на все случаи жизни, как например во фре:

```
truncate file.goy
```

Нужна такая штука для теста из-под MSBiuld скрипта.

Comment: > у винды нет богатых инструментов

а как же эти:  

- power shell
- cygwin

Comment: @jmu, cygwin это скорее богатый инструмент RedHat, а за напоминание о PowerShell и моём невежестве - спасибо, буду исправляться (хотя и не верю в долгую жизнь ps).

@AlexWindHope, мне до вашей личности никакого дела нет. Хотя личность, видимо, очень интересная, если судить по объемам безграмотных текстов, вами производимым. Обоснование было в том треде.

Answer (score 2):

Вот для скрипта не знаю, а для Си (MinGW gcc) есть функция ftruncate(), позволяющая урезать файл.

Простейшая программулька:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 3) {
    fprintf (stderr,"Invalid usage\nUse: truncate SIZE FILE\n");
    exit (1);
  }
  off_t size = atoi(av[1]);
  if (size < 0) // здесь можно что-то другое, например с конца файла
    size = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen(av[2],"r+");
  if (!f) {
    perror(av[2]);
    exit (-1);
  }
  if (ftruncate(fileno(f), size)) {
    perror("truncate");
    exit (-1);
  }
  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: MinGW для поддержки MSBuild немножко отдает велоспортом ;-)

Comment: IMHO в майкрософтовском Си это будет точно также. 

MinGW ведь не тянет библиотек. Попробуйте просто оттранслировать в том, что у Вас есть.

Comment: ошибаетесь. в VC для этого есть io.h и в нем _chsize

Comment: Ну, что тут сказать. Не пользовал Си от М$ и не хочется. Тем более, что там мы наблюдаем такие проблемки (с posix функциями).